# System.InvalidOperationException: The property 'Emp_Status' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I have the following code:

Class

```
public partial class Emp_Details
 {
   public long Emp_ID { get; set; }
   public string Emp_Title { get; set; }
   public string Emp_Name { get; set; }
   public string Emp_LastName { get; set; }
   public string Emp_Status{ get; set; }
 }
```

entity Code

```
      using (LoginEntities dbcontext = new LoginEntities())
          {                
            Emp_Details emp = dbcontext.Emp_Details.Single(i => i.Emp_ID == empid);
              emp.Emp_Status = status;
              dbcontext.SaveChanges();              
          }
```

I am getting the exception

```
  System.InvalidOperationException: The property 'Emp_Status' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified.
```

I have searched for a solution and found 2 possible fixes:

1)Set a primary Key. If there is no primary key on a table, it will simply select the non-nullable columns as a concatenated primary key and the entity will be read/only.

2) Use a direct update such as:

```
 dbcontext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
 "UPDATE Emp_Details SET [Emp_Status] = {0} WHERE [Emp_ID] = {1}", status, empid);
```

Is there any way to do this update without having to touch the database, set primary keys, or mess with the class file?

Answer (score 2):

Your entity doesn't have a primary key. So:

```
public partial class Emp_Details {
   public long Id { get; set; } // pay attention to this
   public string Emp_Title { get; set; }
   public string Emp_Name { get; set; }
   public string Emp_LastName { get; set; }
   public string Emp_Status{ get; set; }
}
```

Or

```
public partial class Emp_Details {
   public long Emp_DetailsId { get; set; } // pay attention to this
   public string Emp_Title { get; set; }
   public string Emp_Name { get; set; }
   public string Emp_LastName { get; set; }
   public string Emp_Status{ get; set; }
}
```

Or

```
public partial class Emp_Details {
   [Key] // pay attention to this
   public long Emp_ID { get; set; }
   public string Emp_Title { get; set; }
   public string Emp_Name { get; set; }
   public string Emp_LastName { get; set; }
   public string Emp_Status{ get; set; }
}
```

Each of above changes, will solve the problem.

Comment: So, this is just doing #1 in the OP's possible solutions, yes?

Comment: @PhatWrat what do you mean? I didn't get it ):

Comment: @Pravin which solution? and Did you update database with last changes (with migration or dbinitializer or custom)?

Comment: Yeah, the original question was hard to follow, and I tried to clarify it, but as it was originally posted: 
1)Set Primary Key or If there is no Primary Key on a table it will simply select the non-nullable columns as a concatenated primary key and the Entity will be read/only  
I was just clarifying that your solution is to do #1.  +1 for showing 3 different ways to go about it.